# In Google Sheets, how can I test if a range of cells contains any of the text in another range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Best explained with an example:

[image]

I want to search the blue range and check if any of the cells contain any of the strings in the green range.

Ideally non-case-sensitive, and the search string could appear anywhere within the searched cells.

Comment: Just want to applaud the well made example.  (I only wrote an answer -- having made the effort to test and such -- because your example is good.) A live sheet is still better though. Not only it makes testing easier, it is also easier to refer to the ranges in answers.

Comment: Thanks! How would I share a live sheet? With a link?

Comment: Yep. Just with a link. (You account name is shared while sharing a sheet. So technically, if you mind the disclosure of name/email, sharing a test sheet may require a test account too. When I ask questions, I just share a sheet temporarily with my personal account and then after answers are in, unshare/delete the sheet.)

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

If...

search range: A1:A10

search key: B1:B3

... then use the following formula

```
=arrayformula(sum(if(regexmatch(textjoin(",",false,",",A1:A10,","),","&B1:B3&","),1,0)))>0
```

Feel free to read the documentation of the functions in question.

The basic idea here is that: we want to be able to join the search words into 1 string and apply `arrayformula` to individual search keys; and then, we want to search whole words.

So how do we easily search whole words? Your search words are divided by cells. So lets put `,` between them but also wrapping them. Now `","&search_key&","` marks a matched word -- not just a component of a search word.

The rest is doing `and` operation on array. Google Sheet unfortunately doesn't have functions like `any` or `all`. So the most (computationally) efficient thing to do is to use `if` (in comparison to alternatives like matrix multiplication or `filter`). The position of `arrayformula` doesn't matter here so you can just put it outside everything.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, very helpful! Your examples fails to catch the "pear" or "fig" inside "fig pear" ... but I'm pretty sure I can find a solution with these ideas.

Comment: @Dan: Ah, I thought you mean all phrases must be strictly divided by cells. If division by spaces are allowed, yes, process those space-including phrases a bit. Probably replace them with the components as well as the total and then into the combined string.

Comment: Got it! `=arrayformula(sum(if(regexmatch(textjoin(" ",false,A5:C5),"(?i)"&$E$1:$E$3),1,0)))>0` seems to work.

Comment: @Dan: Make sure you test search string like "orangeNOT" for search key "orange" and that the formula outputs false. If your cells contain only either single word or multiple words divided by space, ie. "green lime" are two separate words "green" and "lime" that ended up in a single cell, then you can in effect use `" "` as the divider of whole words. But is "green lime" also a valid search key? Can your search keys contain `" "`? If so, you need to include both the parts and the whole. Yet dividing words by `" "` excludes "green lime" as a whole word.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible solution:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(BYROW(A5:C,LAMBDA(r,SUM(LEN(r))))=0,,BYROW(REGEXMATCH(A5:C,"\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b",1,E1:E)&"\b"),LAMBDA(r,SUM(--r)>0))))`

[image]

Note that this formula is entered once in D5 and it doesn't have to be dragged down.

Answer (score 1):

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lchjm.png)

With the recently added new functions, things can be done as easy as this.
The reference range A5:C7 and E1:E3 can be changed to match your needs.

```
=BYROW(A5:C7,LAMBDA(ROW,REGEXMATCH(JOIN(" ",ROW),JOIN("|",$E$1:$E$3))))
```

To make it a 'non-case-sensitive' search, you can add UPPER() to both of the reference range.

Since UPPER() itself is not an ArrayFormula, you'll have to wrap the whole thing with ArrayFormula(), so the outcome will look like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(BYROW(UPPER(A5:C7),LAMBDA(ROW,REGEXMATCH(JOIN(" ",ROW),JOIN("|",UPPER($E$1:$E$3))))))
```

Just found a problem, that if the green range contains empty cells, it may ruin the result, to get rid of this problem, I added QUERY() to the ref. range of green area like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(BYROW(UPPER(A5:C7),LAMBDA(ROW,REGEXMATCH(JOIN(" ",ROW),JOIN("|",UPPER(QUERY({E1:E3},"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")))))))
```

Or, we can include the 'non-case-sensitive' argument into regex2 like this:

```
=BYROW(A5:C7,LAMBDA(ROW,REGEXMATCH(JOIN(" ",ROW),"(?i)"&JOIN("|",QUERY({E1:E3},"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A5:C7),,9^9)), 
 "(?i)\b"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, E1:E)&"\b"))
```

[image]